# What to do if floating point precision causes probabilities that sum above 1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

Suppose I am computing the probability of an event with 3 outcomes `A`, `B`, and `C`.

In the extreme case I have calculated the probability of `A`, denoted `P(A)`, to be zero, and `B`, denoted `P(B)`, to be one, therefore logically the probability of `C` is zero.

However, the computation `P(C) = 1 - P(A) - P(B)` may return a negative small probability due to double precision issues.

What should I do in this case? Do I set `P(C)` to be zero, or is there something clever I can do with `eps`.

Comment: Can you include an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with numbers?

Answer (score 3):

How do you calculate P(A), and P(B)? 
You can always do:

```
P(C) = max(1 - P(A) - P(B),0)
```

Or

```
P(A) = max(min(P(A),1),0)
P(B) = max(min(P(B),1),0)
```

And then `P(C)` will always be between [0,1]